# Accessing variables with javascript (no jQuery) .onmouseup event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, parameter-passing, onmouseup

I am having some trouble understanding how to get a variable to work in my `.onmouseup` event.

I have a `.onmousemove` event that defines a local variable that is, for example the distance the mouse has moved since `.onmousedown`. I want to use that information in a function that executes `.onmouseup`, however, I can't get it there. Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
document.onmousedown = function(){
   var mouseStart = [event.pageX,event.pageY];
   document.onmousemove = function(){
       var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageY-mouseStart[1],2)+Math.pow(event.pageX-mouseStart[0],2));
       document.onmouseup = function() {
          global_function(dist);
          document.onmousemove = null;
      }
   }
}
```

I don't understand why `mouseStart` is accessible but I get the get the error that dist is undefined.

I have other variables that also need to be passed which cannot be redefined during `.onmouseup`.

Comment: Why are you binding an event *inside* an event handler *inside* an event handler?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/VQKrN/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want add the onmouseup event handler inside the onmousedown handler. The mousemove event fires something like 50 times per second in some browsers, so you repeatedly add and remove the mouse up/down events. Then you'll want to declare `dist` inside the mousedown handler.

For browser compatibility, the `event` object gets passed in the event handler by many browsers, and in others it is a global variable. A simple `event = window.event || event` coupled with declaring an `event` argument to the handler does the trick.

```
document.onmousedown = function(event) {
    event = window.event || event;
    var mouseStart = [event.pageX,event.pageY];
    var dist;

    document.onmouseup = function() {
        global_function(dist);
        document.onmousemove = null;
    };

    document.onmousemove = function(ev) {
        ev = window.event || ev;
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ev.pageY-mouseStart[1],2)+Math.pow(ev.pageX-mouseStart[0],2));
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the your function definitions aren't passively inheriting the `event` variable from their closure. You should explicitly accept the `event` variable in the function definition, i.e. `function(event){}`, not `function(){}`.

Also, you're making excessive calculations by computing dist in the mousemove event, it shouldn't be calculated until mouseup.

The following works for me in Firefox.

```
document.onmousedown = function(event){
    var mouseStart = [event.pageX,event.pageY];
    document.onmouseup = function(event) {
        var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageY-mouseStart[1],2)+Math.pow(event.pageX-mouseStart[0],2));
        console.log(dist); //global_function(dist);
        document.onmouseup = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it like this and it worked:

```
document.onmousedown = function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    var mouseStart = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    document.onmouseup = function (ev) {
        var evnt = ev || window.event;
        var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(evnt.pageY - mouseStart[1], 2) + Math.pow(evnt.pageX - mouseStart[0], 2));
        alert(dist);
        document.onmouseup = null;
    };
};
```

As you see I have removed the `onmousemove` event, but it still works with the same result.